# jQuery: Pause function on mousemove or click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've created a function that autoscrolls up and down the page on repeat, I'm now looking to extend this slightly as I want to have to ability to pause the autoscrolling when the user moves the mouse.

Basically the idea is that the page will autoscroll if the user isn't moving their mouse, as soon as they do this function will pause and they'll take over the interaction...until they stop again.

I have a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/neal_fletcher/nxmu74p4/5/).
This scrolls up and down as it should but now I need to pause as soon as an interaction is made, or pause and restart the animation upon clicking the `.start` and `.stop` respectively. My markup as follows:

```
//run instantly and then goes after (setTimeout interval)
function autoScroll() {

    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: $(document).height()
    }, 4000);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 4000);
    }, 4000);
    setInterval(function() {
        // 4000 - it will take 4 secound in total from the top of the page to the bottom
        $("html, body").animate({
            scrollTop: $(document).height()
        }, 4000);
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: 0
            }, 4000);
        }, 4000);

    }, 8000);

}

autoScroll();
```

Any suggestions on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure this jsfiddle is working (http://jsfiddle.net/neal_fletcher/nxmu74p4/5/). I see `ReferenceError: $ is not defined` in the console. When I read your code i see that it should scroll up and down every 4s or something like this

Comment: @sand Yep it works for me – scrolls up and down the page every 4 seconds as it should?

Answer (score 1):

#### The below method will "*pause*" a function (more like the code within it) by checking if a `mouseIsMoving` flag is set or not, as long as the mouse is moving:

```js
var mouseIsMoving,
    // time (ms) after mouse stoped moving to set the flag back to false;
    mouseMoveTime = 500; 
    
window.addEventListener('mousemove', ()=>{  
  clearTimeout(mouseIsMoving);
  mouseIsMoving = setTimeout(()=>{ mouseIsMoving = false }, mouseMoveTime);
});

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// fire some function every 500ms

setInterval(someFunc, 500);

function someFunc(){
  // do whatever ONLY when the mouse is not moving
  if( !mouseIsMoving )
    console.log( new Date().toLocaleTimeString() )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vswcvg5n/) fork of your fiddle.

**HTML**

```
<div style="height:2000px; float:left; width:100%;">
  Text text Text text Text text Text text Text text Text text Text text Text text Text textv Text text Text text Text text Text textText text

</div>

<div class="start">
  START
</div>
<div class="stop">
  STOP
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var autoScrollInterval;
var autoScrollTimeout;
var mouseMoveTimeout = null

function startAutoScroll() {
    autoScroll();
  autoScrollInterval = setInterval(autoScroll, 8000);
}

function autoScroll() {
  $("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: $(document).height()
  }, 4000);
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: 0
    }, 4000);
  }, 4000);
}

$(document).on('mousemove', function() {
    // Stop animation
        $("html, body").stop();

    // clear timeouts and intervals
    clearTimeout(mouseMoveTimeout);
    clearTimeout(autoScrollTimeout);
        clearInterval(autoScrollInterval);

    mouseMoveTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
        // restore auto scrolling
        startAutoScroll();
    }, 1000);
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  startAutoScroll();
});
```

In short I used jQuery's [mousemove](https://api.jquery.com/mousemove/) to detect if mouse is moving and then clear intervals and timeouts.

If you want to change the time when autoscroll should start again change it here, now is set to 1 second:

```
mouseMoveTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
        // restore auto scrolling
        startAutoScroll();
}, 1000); // change time when autoscroll starts here
```

**EDIT**

Your statement is good that autoscroll should be disabled when user is scrolling and I made such version of the code [**HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/vswcvg5n/1/)

Now we take care for `DOMMouseScroll`(when browser is Firefox) and `mousewheel` events because `$().on('scroll')` will disable the whole code snippet to work(we should detect if scroll is made by the user).

**UPDATED JS**

```
var autoScrollInterval;
var autoScrollTimeout;
var restoreTimeout = null

function autoScroll() {
  $("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: $(document).height()
  }, 4000);
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: 0
    }, 4000);
  }, 4000);
}

function startAutoScroll() {
  autoScroll();
  autoScrollInterval = setInterval(autoScroll, 8000);
}

function stopAutoScroll() {
  // Stop animation
  $("html, body").stop();

  // clear timeouts and intervals
  clearTimeout(restoreTimeout);
  clearTimeout(autoScrollTimeout);
  clearInterval(autoScrollInterval);

  restoreTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
    // restore auto scrolling
    startAutoScroll();
  }, 1000);
}

//Firefox
$(document).bind('DOMMouseScroll', function(e) {
  stopAutoScroll()
});

//IE, Opera, Safari
$(document).bind('mousewheel', function(e) {
  stopAutoScroll()
});

$(document).on('mousemove', function() {
    stopAutoScroll();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  startAutoScroll();
});
```

Comment: this is pretty close – definitely the best answer yet. Just a few things, it's a bit buggy, it does indeed pause on mouse move but when you start scrolling independently it keeps scrolling too and jars a bit, should also pause on scroll too? Also on click of `.stop`

Comment: Yes you are right this is a good point, we should disable autoscroll on scrolling too, I will update